# What is the VS2012 equivalent of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying to get the temp directory and store some variables in it. The code that I found to get the temp dir is

```
string temp = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tmp");
```

But this gives me an error,

> System.Environment does not contain a definition for
>   'GetEnvironmentVariable'.

I've also tried

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
```

How can I reach the temp directory in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Are you targeting the client runtime or the full rutime (check your project properties).

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tmp") is the wrong way to get the temporary path. The correct way is `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`

Comment: string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(); didn't work either.

Comment: You tried, but what happened with `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();`

Comment: Gave me an error that System.IO.Path does not a definition for 'GetTempPath'.

Comment: Well let's try to sort that out, but let's be clear that poking at environment variables isn't how you find out the temp path

Comment: Is this is a Windows Store app?

Comment: Yea, it is a Win Store app.

Comment: Well, why didn't you say so?!

Comment: Well, I had. And then a couple of people edited the tags.

Comment: Come on, please try to provide details. People want to help, but you need to try and provide all details you can. VS2012 is not only for Windows store apps development. Hell, I have been using it for months and haven't writtent a single winrt app.

Comment: Sorry! Will do in the future.

Comment: You tagged it windows-8 which is not the same as windows store / winrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `winrt`, you can get a temp path like so:

```
StorageFolder temp = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
```

More details on different folders you can access - http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/

Comment: Thanks. I'll proceed with this.